# I want to print the icons on my html page

Tags: html, css, icons

In this code I linked some icons in to my html page. I want to print them in my html page. How  can I do it?. I don't get any sufficient answer on my searches so apologies if this is a duplicate. 
in this [link](http://w3schools.com/icons)they have shown how to style icons loaded from internet using  and  tag,instead of internet i want to load from my computer using the same tags,can you help me?

```
<html>
    <head>
       <!-- <link rel="stylesheet" href="make.css">
        <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="57x57" href="/apple-icon-57x57.png">-->
        <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="icona.png" sizes="32x32" />
         <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="iconb.png" sizes="32x32" />
         <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="iconc.png" sizes="32x32" />
         <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="icond.png" sizes="32x32" />
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="favicon-16x16.png" sizes="16x16" />
    </head>
    <body>

    </body>
</html>
```

for example here the `<i>` tag is used to load an icon.

```
<a id="fa-flag" href="javascript:;" onClick="$C.setIcon()">
  <i class="fa fa-flag"> </i>fa-flag
</a>
```

Comment: Do you want to display the icons in html page and print the page ?

Comment: no i just want to display icons in html page

Comment: The OP's question is misleading. Above looks like they want to load an image file, from comments it appears they want to apply FontAwesome styling to their own icon files (which isn't really applicable).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`link`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/link) tags you are using are for setting the pages favicon icon (icon in the browser tab).

To add the image to the HTML page for rendering, you'd need to add an [`img`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/img) tag within the document's body.

```
<body>
   <img src="favicon-32x32.png" height="32" width="32" />
<body>
```

Comment: @dreamhunter Can you please clarify what you mean by icon color? You can apply CSS Filters (https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/f/filter/), but unless the filter needs to be dynamic it's suggested to edit the image before uploading it to minimize computation.

Comment: @mplungjan You can inspect my answer, I got downvoted too. :/

Comment: I did, hence the comment

Comment: in the above link they have shown how to style icons loaded from internet using <span> and <i> tag,instead of internet i want to load from my computer using the same tags,can you help me?

Comment: @dreamhunter The link you posted is to a library called font-awesome, that created icons from elements. You don't specify a file-path. Look at their code example http://www.w3schools.com/icons/tryit.asp?filename=tryicons_awesome

Comment: What you're looking for is adding `<span class="fa fa-cloud"></span>` to your page, but change `fa-cloud` to the specific icon you're looking to add, you can use this official page for reference, http://fontawesome.io/icons/ . That page lists all the icons and their classNames that must be referenced.

Comment: The reason why you can add color and distort FontAwesome icons is because that library renders them as text, they aren't actually images (jpg, png, etc). You can't apply text color styling to images. To achieve a similar affect you'd need to use css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/f/filter, but keep in mind this won't look exactly the same with semi-transparent images.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot use link tag for displaying icons on your page. Its use is to load external stylesheets and setting icon of browser tab( favicon ). You can refer the following [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/link) for more details.

To display images you can do two things :-

1) By an **img** tag :-

```
<body>
   <img src="icona.png" height="32" width="32" />
   <img src="iconb.png" height="32" width="32" />
   <img src="iconc.png" height="32" width="32" />
   <img src="icond.png" height="32" width="32" />
   <img src="favicon-16X16.png" height="16" width="16" />
<body>
```

2) By a **div** tag :-

html:-

```
<body>
   <div class="image-icona" height="32" width="32"></div>
<body>
```

css:-

```
.image-icona{
    width: 32px;
    height: 32px;
    background-image: url("../img/icona.png");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: contain;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**IMG  TAG**

You need to use `img` tag to display a picture in the webpage

**LINK TAG**

The  tag is used for defining a link to an external document.

Comment: Why the downvote? Donvotes without comments are useless.

Comment: `the tag is used to link to external style sheets.` and no other suggestion?

Comment: I did. It is not answering the question and link is used for many other things than style sheets

Comment: Improve your answer to get the down vote removed - no need to take it personally. Instead see it as a constructive criticism

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/121327/discussion-between-shahil-and-mplungjan).

Comment: I deleted my answer. It did not answer the actual question asked.